# VHDL: how to represent signed/unsigned as integer string when >32 bits

Tags: vhdl

I am doing a bunch of DSP verification and for printing when assertions fail, I wrote these functions for signed and unsigned types:

```
    function to_string(arg : integer) return string is
    begin
        return integer'image(arg);
    end function;

    function to_string(arg : signed) return string is
    begin
        return to_string(to_integer(arg));
    end function;

    function to_string(arg : unsigned) return string is
    begin
        return to_string(to_integer(arg));
    end function;
```

However, they just broke as some of my results are larger than 32 bits wide. Is there a way in VHDL to provide an integer string representation of signed and unsigned types when they're greater than 32 bits wide? If not, can someone provide a function for providing the hex representation of these numbers to reduce the size of what is printed to the console?

Comment: Maybe you can benefit from `real` type, since that is always [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), thus have more bits to represent the integer part.

Comment: @MortenZilmer  That would be nice, but when dealing with signed/unsigned types, this is not possible as I have to convert to integer first. My use case is I am verifying signed/unsigned results that have widths >31 bits. When checking the values I am okay since I use the same data type. However, I would like to print expected/observed to the screen in a readable fashion for the user to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hex representation is provided for free in VHDL 2008 in the numeric_std package via the to_hstring function. to_string and to_ostring are also provided.

These functions were provided for all bit-based types in their native packages. write, owrite and hwrite are also provided for writing to a line.

Comment: Cool, it looks like I'll be switching to '08 at least for all my testbenches since it looks like all the simulators I use support the things I would need. Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't realize they added this as we've been stuck on '02.

Answer (score 1):

The VUnit string_ops package provides such functions: https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/blob/3de8d229ca7b4ba3db395f3981a3ea107cf67c72/vunit/vhdl/string_ops/src/string_ops.vhd#L611.